# Jmeter vs Gatling for performance testing 2020

Tags: java, scala, jmeter, gatling

I am trying to compare Gatling to Jmeter for performance testing.

My requirements is:

1. I want compatibility with CI/CD and automation.
2. Performance should be good  (I know Gatling is a bit better performance in regard resource hogging).
3. Dynamic -> i.e. able to run a test, change some settings in the environment, and then run the test again.
4. Use on Cloud (I feel like because Gatling is better for performance, it would be better for the cloud... But I don't know if there really is a big difference here).
5. I am testing a ***Monolith*** system, so I wont be able to split up the system as well (as microservices), and using mocks(mockito) will be harder to be able to get more exact performance on for example a request for an endpoint, excluding database time, etc. So this kind of means the performance test I suppose I will be doing is more of a stress test and testing general performance of system, rather then getting measurements of isolated parts of system.

Any help would be great. I ask because a lot of information seems to be out of date on this...

Edit: I amn't afraid of Gatling being programmed in Scala and gatling dsl. Im more afraid of limitations and gotchas that i amnt seeing!

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: Gatling creator here

IMHO, first criterion should actually be: which tool would you feel the most comfortable with?

Gatling is code oriented, integrates nicely with IDEs such as IntelliJ or vscode.
JMeter is GUI oriented.

If you know about programming, you might prefer Gatling so you can use your usual dev environment and practices (refactoring, peer review, etc). You don't need to be a dev expert, you'll be mostly using Gatling's DSL (make sure to read the [official documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/) and go through the tutorials).

On the contrary, if you can't code (and don't want to learn the basics such as methods, parameters, IDE), you shouldn't go with Gatling and go with JMeter instead.

Note: if you're looking for a cloud based platform for Gatling, we provide [Gatling FrontLine](https://gatling.io/gatling-frontline/).

Comment: Cool I should have added that I wasn't thrown off by Gatling being in Scala (I actually really love Scala).. Il edit now... My fear was limitations etc. that I wasn't aware of

Comment: The only limitation I can think of is we don't support legacy auth schemes such as NTLM or Kerberos (demand has always been scarce and dried out in the last years).

Comment: Stéphane LANDELLE, in your opinion, is Gatling more CI friendly? I have heard this from afew sources, but none have been as official as someone who is one of the  "Gatling creators".. I see that JMeter has other tools you could use with it such a Taurus and Jenkins, but is Gatling just easier to work into CI? (maybe by the fact it is code and not xml).

Comment: I can't speak for other tools. When running from a CI, the important thing is to deploy your load injectors on hosts where they don't have to compete with other processes for resources (eg, not a Jenkins slave that would compile another project or run some Selenium tests at the same time...). FrontLine is especially designed with CI in mind: it takes care of injectors provisioning, stats real time collecting, dashboards, etc. If you want to stick with OSS, you'll have to build this yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I will look more into Gatling Frontline then!

Comment: First, make sure to check that you like Gatling. Feel also free to join our community mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gatling

Answer (score 2):

Both tools support all your requirements so it's rather a matter of personal preference/experience.

1. Gatling supports less protocols out of the box (limited to [HTTP](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http), [JMS](https://gatling.io/docs/current/jms/) and [MQTT](https://gatling.io/docs/current/mqtt/)) than [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers), however it is possible to extend both and add support of the protocol(s) of your choice
2. You will need to do [some extra manual work in order to set up Gatling distributed testing](https://gatling.io/docs/current/cookbook/scaling_out#scaling-out-with-gatling-open-source) while JMeter aggregates data from the slaves automatically in [Distributed Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)
3. Gatling is more CI friendly as it assumes writing tests in Scala while supported way of creating a JMeter test is using GUI and [JMeter test plan](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) is XML file and adding a single test element will result in 10+ lines of XML code which is not very readable.

Answer (score 0):

Both support your requirements,

JMeter :

1. but more than gatling its easy in JMeter for correlation & Parameterisation.
2. In JMeter we have recorded response which allows for details correlation.
3. In JMeter Tagging Transaction names, Creating checkpoints for validation & verification,  a structured UI support.
   overall script creation/ recording is easier in JMeter than in gatling.

Gatling :

1. Gatling has a code scripting facility which is not a case in JMeter.
2. Gatling uses less memory, Disk than JMeter
3. Gatling is better with creating and handling more V-user, Thread re-use than JMeter.

@user3038404 now gatling also support Java & Gardle for PT (could be suitable for you)